# iOS WebView > Display only main-content from a website including pictures

Tags: iphone, ios5, uiwebview, html

How do I fetch just the main-content part of a webpage and display it in an UIWEBVIEW?
[Link to the page](http://golfplatz-altenstadt.de/)

When I look at the code of the webpage I see that the 'What is new?' posts appear below:

```
<div id="content-header" class="clearfix">
                  <a name="main-content" id="main-content"></a>
          <h1 class="title">Aktuell</h1>                                      </div> <!-- /#content-header -->
```

Is it possible to relate to `id="main-content` within the UIWEBVIEW to 
display just this part of the website instead of the whole page?

Screenshot shows visually what I like to get.

[image: Screenshot]

P.S This is my code to display the whole webpage:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *golfClubURL = @"http://golfplatz-altenstadt.de";

    NSURL *loungeURL = [NSURL URLWithString:golfClubURL];

    NSURLRequest *myrequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:loungeURL];

    [self.webView loadRequest:myrequest];

    self.webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for a generic way to handle this?   By generic, I mean a way that works for all web pages.  Or is this just to grab the news from this page?

Comment: For now I'm looking to just grab the news from this particular page.

Comment: Like to add: If you have a way for generically getting particular parts of any webpages I'm happy to hear about it.

Comment: have you solved this problem?

Comment: Nope, unfortunately not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The process to make this work is to load the URL in to a string, and then modify the string, and then send the string to display in the UIWebView.

It will require you to parse the html.  You will probably be best off cutting out just what part you want, and adding in a header and footer.

You might want to look at [NSURLConnection](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Do you own the website?  You might want to create an alternative page of the site that shows a more mobile friendly version of the page.  If it is a blog, or running something like wordpress there are plug-ins for mobile templates.  This has an added benefit of giving a fast easy to read version of the site for anyone using any mobile device.

Comment: I do not own this site, it's from my golf club. I independently looking for a way to get all this none mobile friendly content nicely formatted & transferred to the iPhone. Unfortunately there is no API available. Nor it's a blog or build on any known website templates like wordpress for example. To your suggestion, doesn't the App then always fetch the whole website? I was looking for a way to just get the 'What is new' posts loaded to get the content quickly.

Comment: Yes it will always download the whole web page, so you have to download it all, then look thru it to find just what you want to display in the app.  --This approach is fragile, since they can change the page any time, and that would break your code, since what your looking for as the start and end of the information you want to display can be modified.

Comment: Thanks for help and clarification, will study NSURLConnection Class to see what I can do, maybe my Golfclub will help me and modify the site for a better mobile experience.